# How to customize the color scale in a D3 line chart?

Tags: d3.js, colors

How do I change the color of lines in a d3 line chart, for example in Mike Bostock's multi-series D3 [line chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).

In his example chart, Mike Bostock uses D3's built-in "category10" color scale, as per this line of code:

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();
```

But suppose, instead of the built-in scale, we wanted the line for Austin to be blue, the line for New York to be red, and the line for San Francisco to be green. Should be simple enough, right? Just define a custom color scale:

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"])
    .range("#FF0000", "#009933" , "#0000FF");
```

I thought that might do the trick – but it turns all the series black. I've tried CSS styling each series by appending classes to them, but that didn't work.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this without having to define the city names. So the first line is red, second line is blue etc regardless of the key?

Comment: @DaRoGa, you probably already figured this out but just in case: `.domain([1, 2, 3 ...])` will do the trick. Just make sure they correspond to the colors in your `.range([...])`. Then you can use `color(i)` to retrieve your color based on index.

Comment: You dont even need to include the domain if you just want the colors

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You're only missing the square brackets around the values in `.range()` -- it takes an array as argument. So the code should be

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal() // D3 Version 4
  .domain(["New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"])
  .range(["#FF0000", "#009933" , "#0000FF"]);
```

Complete example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/8494327).

Comment: Your example actually uses v3.

Answer (score 12):

for D3 v4

```
   let color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(["New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"])
      .range(["#FF0000", "#009933" , "#0000FF"]);
```