# d3.scale.category10() + d3 + other color categories

Tags: d3.js, colors, scale

Can anyone explain the different color categories available in d3?

And is my understanding correct? I am currently using this `d3.scale.category10();` but this only gives me 10 colors and then starts reusing the colors after the 10th object. My thinking is I can use `d3.scale.category20b();` to give 20 different colors to 20 different objects. But is there any other color categories available? And what is the difference between `20b` and `20c`?

These are the ones I have found so far:

`d3.scale.category10();
d3.scale.category20b();
d3.scale.category20c();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the (very well documented) [d3 github page](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#color-schemes-d3-scale-chromatic), you can see the actual colors for each of the predefined color scales.

You could also take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208031/how-to-customize-the-color-scale-in-a-d3-line-chart) for how to define your own.

Comment: tks, scrolled down to `Categorical Colors` to get exactly what I wanted