# Having trouble with updating D3.js multiline chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am fairly new to D3 and am hitting a problem.

I've created a simplied example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Firstly, I have a CSV file with data. In this example, it consists of phone sales data for some popular phones for several months for 2 stores. The data is shown below:

```
Store,Product,Month,Sold
London,iPhone,0,5
London,iPhone,1,4
London,iPhone,2,3
London,iPhone,3,5
London,iPhone,4,6
London,iPhone,5,7
London,Android Phone,0,3
London,Android Phone,1,4
London,Android Phone,2,5
London,Android Phone,3,7
London,Android Phone,4,8
London,Android Phone,5,9
London,Windows Phone,0,1
London,Windows Phone,1,2
London,Windows Phone,2,6
London,Windows Phone,3,7
London,Windows Phone,4,8
London,Windows Phone,5,5
Glasgow,iPhone,0,3
Glasgow,iPhone,1,4
Glasgow,iPhone,2,5
Glasgow,iPhone,3,2
Glasgow,iPhone,4,1
Glasgow,iPhone,5,3
Glasgow,Android Phone,0,4
Glasgow,Android Phone,1,3
Glasgow,Android Phone,2,7
Glasgow,Android Phone,3,4
Glasgow,Android Phone,4,3
Glasgow,Android Phone,5,6
Glasgow,Windows Phone,0,3
Glasgow,Windows Phone,1,6
Glasgow,Windows Phone,2,7
Glasgow,Windows Phone,3,5
Glasgow,Windows Phone,4,3
Glasgow,Windows Phone,5,4
```

I've written the following code in JS/D3.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    svg {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .x.axis path {
      fill:none;
      stroke:#000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

</style>
<body>
    <p id="menu"><b>Test</b>
    <br>Select Store: 
    <select>
        <option value="0">London</option>
        <option value="1">Glasgow</option>
   </select>
   </p>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>


var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// construct a linear scale for x axis
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0,width]);

// construct a linear scale for y axis
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height,0]);

// use the default line colours (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208031/how-to-customize-the-color-scale-in-a-d3-line-chart for info on setting colours per line)
var color = d3.scale.category10();

// create the x axis and orient of ticks and labels at the bottom
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

// create the y axis and orient of ticks and labels on the left
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

// line generator function
var line = d3.svg.line()
    //.interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.Sold); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.csv("sampleData.csv", function(error, data) {


       color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key == "Product"; }));

    // first we need to corerce the data into the right formats
        // map the data from the CSV file
      data = data.map( function (d) { 
        return { 
          Store: d.Store,
          Product: d.Product,
          Month: +d.Month,
          Sold: +d.Sold }; 
    });   


    // nest the data by regime and then CI
    var salesDataByStoreProduct = d3.nest()
          .key(function(d) { return d.Store; })
          .key(function(d) { return d.Product; })         
          .entries(data);

    // get the first regime's nest
    var salesDataForLondon;
    salesDataForLondon = salesDataByStoreProduct[0].values;

    console.log(salesDataForLondon);

    x.domain([d3.min(salesDataForLondon, function(d) { return d3.min(d.values, function (d) { return d.Month; }); }),
             d3.max(salesDataForLondon, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function (d) { return d.Month; }); })]);
    y.domain([0, d3.max(salesDataForLondon, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function (d) { return d.Sold; }); })]);


      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis);


      var Products = svg.selectAll(".Product")
          .data(salesDataForLondon, function(d) { return d.key; })
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "Product");

      Products.append("path")
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
          .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.key); });

    function redraw()
    {
        var salesDataByStoreProduct = d3.nest()
          .key(function(d) { return d.Store; })
          .key(function(d) { return d.Product; })         
          .entries(data);

        var salesDataForGlasgow;
        salesDataForGlasgow = salesDataByStoreProduct[1].values;

        console.log(salesDataForGlasgow);

        x.domain([d3.min(salesDataForGlasgow, function(d) { return d3.min(d.values, function (d) { return d.Product; }); }),
                 d3.max(salesDataForGlasgow, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function (d) { return d.Product; }); })]);
        y.domain([0, d3.max(salesDataForGlasgow, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function (d) { return d.Sales; }); })]);


          svg.select("g")
              .call(xAxis);

          svg.select("g")
              .call(yAxis);


          var Products = svg.selectAll(".Product")
              .data(salesDataForGlasgow, function(d) { return d.key; })
            .enter().select("g")
              .attr("class", "Product");

          Products.select("path")
              .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
              .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.key); });

    }

    /******************************************************/
 var menu = d3.select("#menu select")
    .on("change", change);   


function change() 
{
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    d3.transition()
    .duration(altKey ? 7500 : 1500);
    redraw();
}
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
  menu.property("value", "ENEUSE").node().focus();
  change();
}, 7000);

var altKey;
d3.select(window)
    .on("keydown", function() { altKey = d3.event.altKey; })
    .on("keyup", function() { altKey = false; });

/******************************************************/

});                    

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

where I've read in the CSV file and then used D3 nests to create a hierarchy as shown below:

Store->Product->Month->Sales

I want the chart to present the sales data per product by month for London and then if the selection is changed, to show the sales data by month for Glasgow.

However, although the London data is being presented, the chart isn't being updated when I select Glasgow.

To rule out anything too obvious, I've hardcoded the array index for each store.

I've also added console.log and can see the right data is being used but just not rendered in the chart when redraw() is being called.

I'd be grateful of any suggestions of the cause of the problem which I suspect it related to the following code:

```
var Products = svg.selectAll(".Product")
.data(salesDataForGlasgow, function(d) { return d.key; })
.enter().select("g")
.attr("class", "Product");

Products.select("path")
.attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
.style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.key); });
```

Any other advice on improving or simplifying the code would be very gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, the problem is indeed in these two statements:

```
      var Products = svg.selectAll(".Product")
          .data(salesDataForGlasgow, function(d) { return d.key; })
        .enter().select("g")
          .attr("class", "Product");

      Products.select("path")
          .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
          .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.key); });
```

`Products` is derived from the `.enter()` selection.  This contains one element for each data item that isn't joined to an existing element in the DOM.  When changing the graph to show the Glasgow data, there are no new elements to add (the London data has three products as does the Glasgow data), so the `.enter()` selection is empty.

Instead, you need to restart the selection from `.Product`.  Change the second of the two statements to the following:

```
      svg.selectAll(".Product")
          .select("path")
          .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
          .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.key); });
```

There are some other issues I found in your code.  Firstly, the three lines that set `x.domain()` and `y.domain()` use the wrong property names at the end.  This causes various `NaN`s to appear in the ranges of the `x` and `y` scales as D3 attempts to convert product names or `undefined` to numbers.  At the end of these three lines, replace `d.Product` with `d.Month` and `d.Sales` with `d.Sold`, so that they are consistent with the lines that set the ranges of the `x` and `y` scales for the London sales data.

Finally, you need to adjust how you reset the axes.  At the moment you are using the following code:

```
      svg.select("g")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.select("g")
          .call(yAxis);
```

This ends calling the `xAxis` and then `yAxis` functions on all `g` elements, including both axes, all axis ticks and the three graph lines, so the graph looks a bit confused.  You've set the `class` of the X-axis to `x axis`, but because class names can't have spaces in you've actually given the axis the classes `x` and `axis`.  A similar thing happens with the y-axis.

What you need to do is to select the axes individually, using the classes you've assigned to them, before calling `xAxis` or `yAxis`.  Replace the lines above with the following:

```
      svg.select("g.x.axis")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.select("g.y.axis")
          .call(yAxis);
```

After you've made all these changes the graph should hopefully do what you want.

Comment: Many thanks Luke. Combined with Mark's code below, I've been able to resolve the issue. I'll repost the working code.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a code review site, your code could take significant refactoring.  First, you aren't handling the enter, update, exit pattern correctly.  Second, once you handle the pattern correctly you don't need a seperate `redraw` function.  Just one function to handle creation and update.

Here's a quick refactor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .x.axis path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <p id="menu"><b>Test</b>
    <br>Select Store:
    <select>
      <option value="London">London</option>
      <option value="Glasgow">Glasgow</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // construct a linear scale for x axis
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([0, width]);

    // construct a linear scale for y axis
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    // use the default line colours (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208031/how-to-customize-the-color-scale-in-a-d3-line-chart for info on setting colours per line)
    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    // create the x axis and orient of ticks and labels at the bottom
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    // create the y axis and orient of ticks and labels on the left
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    // line generator function
    var line = d3.svg.line()
      //.interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.Month);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.Sold);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // create gs for axis but don't add yet
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis");

    var salesDataByStoreProduct = null;
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

      color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
        return key == "Product";
      }));

      // first we need to corerce the data into the right formats
      // map the data from the CSV file
      data = data.map(function(d) {
        return {
          Store: d.Store,
          Product: d.Product,
          Month: +d.Month,
          Sold: +d.Sold
        };
      });

      // nest the data by regime and then CI
      salesDataByStoreProduct = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.Store;
        })
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.Product;
        })
        .entries(data);

      draw("London");

    });

    function draw(which) {

      // get the first regime's nest
      var salesData = null;
      salesDataByStoreProduct.forEach(function(d) {
        if (d.key === which) {
          salesData = d.values;
        }
      });

      // set domains
      x.domain([d3.min(salesData, function(d) {
          return d3.min(d.values, function(d) {
            return d.Month;
          });
        }),
        d3.max(salesData, function(d) {
          return d3.max(d.values, function(d) {
            return d.Month;
          });
        })
      ]);
      y.domain([0, d3.max(salesData, function(d) {
        return d3.max(d.values, function(d) {
          return d.Sold;
        });
      })]);

      // draw axis
      svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);    
      svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

      // this is the update selection
      var Products = svg.selectAll(".Product")
        .data(salesData, function(d) {
          return d.key;
        });

      // this is the enter selection
      Products
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "Product")
        .append("path");

      // now do update
      Products.selectAll("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return line(d.values);
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
          return color(d.key);
        });
    }

    var menu = d3.select("#menu select")
      .on("change", change);

    function change() {
      draw(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Running code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hLu7Us07tMufqeO4Musi?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks Mark. Although at first glance, it looks like your code is working, I don't think it is as it's presenting the same data but rescaling the axes. I'm trying to establish why

Comment: I resolved the issue with your suggested code by changing:

    Products.selectAll("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return line(d.values);
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
          return color(d.key);
        });
to:

    svg.selectAll(".Product")
          .select("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
          .style("stroke", function(d) { 
     return color(d.key); 
   });

That appears to have resolved the issue. Many thanks again for the sample code.

Comment: @JamesSaunders, my apologies.  It meant to type `Products.select("path").attr("d", function(d) ... `.  Note, that's a `select` and not `selectAll`.  See [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/#conclusion) for the details of why I screwed that up!  Answering questions too fast sometimes...  Corrected plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/MGjzEiGOQi7sUeC6nUuP?p=preview