# how to set color gradient in barchart using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

i have following code

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.value = +d.value;
    });
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var y1 = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("#bar").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis().scale(y1)
    .orient("left");             
var line = d3.svg.line()
             .interpolate("basis")
             .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
             .y(function(d) { return y1(d.avg_return); }); 

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
  y1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { 
    return d.avg_return; })]);
/*for x axis*/
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );
/*for y axis*/
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value ($)");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill",function(d) { if (d.value >= 400) {return "green"} else if (d.value<=300) { return "red" } else { return 'yellow'} })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
  svg.append('path')
     .datum(data)
     .attr('class', 'sparkline')
     .attr('d', line);
  svg.append('circle')
     .attr('class', 'sparkcircle')
     .attr('cx', x(data[0].date))
     .attr('cy', y1(data[0].avg_return))
     .attr('r', 2.5);      
    svg.append("g")       
        .attr("class", "y axis")  
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)") 
        .style("fill", "red")   
        .call(yAxisRight);
});
```

my csv file contains following data

```
date,value,avg_return
a,530,70
b,490,91
c,450,92
d,400,78
e,370,50
f,340,56
D,300,32
h,250,96
a9,200,73
```

i have use color gradient for this colors(#D73027,#FFFFBF,#1A9850).
how to use color gradient in bar chart..i have to sett colors based on the (value column)

Comment: Your code doesnt even run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here : [How to customize the color scale in a D3 line chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208031/how-to-customize-the-color-scale-in-a-d3-line-chart)

I have created your custom color scale :

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal() 
  .range(["#D73027", "#FFFFBF" , "#1A9850"]);
```

And edited how you fill your bars :

```
.style("fill", function(d,i){
  return color(i); //pass i to scale
  })
```

Notice I pass `i` to the color scale. If there aren't enough colors in the scale it will wrap round and start again.

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/snjb4q92/2/

Edit

You say you want 'boundaries'. So what I have done, if its between 0 and 300, take first color, 300 and 400 takes second and 400 and 600 takes third.

Logic :

```
.style("fill", function(d, i) {
    if (d.value >= 0 && d.value < 300) {
      return color(0);
    } else if (d.value >= 300 && d.value < 400) {
      return color(1);
    } else if (d.value >= 400 && d.value < 600) {
      return color(2);
    }

  })
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/snjb4q92/6/

Comment: but i want color based on column(value)

Comment: example value columns contain 500 to 200 means i have to take color high to low

Comment: Considering you only have 3 colors you want to show this wont work. Youll have to implement a larger scale like so : 
var color = d3.scale.category10()  , updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/snjb4q92/3/

Comment: if value is 500 means it take green then based on value the color have to change

Comment: So what boundaries do you want ?

Comment: low,medium,high[-1,0,1]

Comment: I have edited the answer. Low medium high makes no sense, what is classed as low ? medium ? or high ? I have edited the answer to get you started. It should solve the problem